# view users that login

Tags: c#, asp.net, authentication

when user=admin and pass=1234 login in page login.aspx login.

in page product.aspx how can access this user (that valid uset)without login aging

```
protected void btnligon_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (user.Text == "admin" && pass.Text == "12abAB!@")
        Response.Redirect("dialog1.aspx");
    else
        mess.InnerText = "login fail";
}
```

Comment: what? and did you just wrote your admin password?

Comment: Generally this is not the way people implement a login, although if you only ever have one user for one internal site it will work, but it's still not a good practice.

ASP.Net has a good built in Membership system which is perfectly suitable for matching login details for a user. 

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yh26yfzy.aspx
http://www.asp.net/security/tutorials/creating-the-membership-schema-in-sql-server-cs

As for your question I'm not really sure what you're asking. Could you clarify what you are trying to do in more details?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suggest using Forms Authentication with the credentials in your web.config.

```
<authentication mode="Forms"> 
    <forms name="Auth"  requireSSL="false"
           loginUrl="~/login.aspx" defaultUrl="~/default.aspx" >
    <credentials passwordFormat="Clear">
         <user name="SomeUserName" password="SomePassword"/>    
    </credentials>
    </forms>
</authentication>
<authorization>
    <deny users="?" />
</authorization>
```